# while generating GET/PUT URl in jclouds , how i can set headers for aws-s3, if possible please provide example refrence

Tags: java, jclouds

Below is my requirement.

1) i need to generate PUT url for aws-s3 using jclouds.
      i have successfully generate the URL with below code.

```
   HttpRequest request = context.getSigner().signPutBlob(bucketName, blob, expriyTime);

   url = request.getEndpoint();

   https://buketName.s3.amazonaws.com/test/newFile.txt?Expires=1422036847&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXX&Signature=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY.
```

but I want URL should contain server side encryption param in query String.
 https://buketName.s3.amazonaws.com/test/newFile.txt?Expires=1422036847&x-amz-server-side-encryption=AES256&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXX&Signature=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY.

but in header i need to send headers like "x-amz-copy-source" , "x-amz-server-side-encryption".  Please help me how can achieve this using jclouds.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the generated request easily by invoking the `toBuilder()` method:

```java
HttpRequest request = context.getSigner().signPutBlob(bucketName, blob, expriyTime);
HttpRequest withParams = request.toBuilder()
    .addQueryParam("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256")
    .build();
```